# Django: Link a field of one model to a field of another

Tags: python, django, database, models

I'm working through the Tango with Django book and have decided to add some of my own functionality but have an issue.

I have two models, Category and Page

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Now what I'm trying to do is make the Category "views" field a sum of the views of all of the pages within that category

In my test database population script I am doing it this way:

```
cats = {"Python": {"pages": python_pages,
                   "views": sum(page["views"] for page in python_pages),
                   },
        "Django": {"pages": django_pages,
                   "views": sum(page["views"] for page in django_pages),
                   },
        "Other Frameworks": {"pages": other_pages,
                             "views": sum(page["views"] for page in other_pages),
                             }
        }
```

This works for the populating the database, but how would I make it so that the category "views" updates whenever a page "views" field is changed?

For example if two different pages in the same category's "views" go up by one, category's "views" would go up by two?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this, rather than calculating the views when you actually need it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Not necessarily, really my only requirement is to have the "category" views update when the "page" views go up. I'm not set on any one particular way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

I would add this to your category class instead of using the views field:

```
def get_views(self):
    views=0
    for page in pages_set:
        views+=page.views
    return views
```

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate this when you need it, rather than storing it. You can do it with an aggregation on the set of related objects for your category:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
my_category.page_set.aggregate(Sum('views'))
```

or use annotationif you need to get several categories at once with their view count:

```
Category.objects.all().annotate(Sum('page__count'))
```